# Getting specific item from String array

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, string

I have a string array say

```
<string-array name="temp">
    <item>
        Some Data1
    </item>
    <item>
        Some Data2
    </item>
    <item>
        Some Data3
    </item>
</string-array>
```

Suppose I want to get Some Data2 from this array, I know I can do

```
String temp[]=getResource().getStringArray(R.array.temp);
```

But instead of getting whole string array, I want only a specific item because data of whole string is too large, and I know its position. Please help.

Comment: you can not get a single item directly , you have get the whole array and  then get the data use temp[1]....

Comment: Sir the thing is that I don't want to get whole array because data is too large, so I only want to get item but not array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the entry you want is at position 2 (just an example), then do:

```
String myEntry = getResource().getStringArray(R.array.temp)[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.But If you want to do that just create string array in java class like

```
String arr[] = {"item1","item2","item3"}.
```

And access those value using `arr[1];`